# jQuery validations plugin does not work with jQuery SimpleModal plugin after closing and reopening modal dialog

Tags: jquery, simplemodal, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery 1.7.1, jQuery Validations plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) 1.9.0, jQuery SimpleModal plugin (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) 1.4.2 and jQuery qTip2 (http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/).

I have a few forms that need to be opened in modal dialog boxes.  Validations work when the modal dialog boxes are opened for the first time.  However, when I close a dialog box and reopen it, the validations are not performed again.

I attach form validations using the onShow callback of the SimpleModal plugin (so they are applied every time the modal box is created, not just at page load).

See http://jsfiddle.net/NVvFh/22/ for a demo.

Do note that I have tried persist: true with SimpleModal.  That creates other problems.

Any help on getting the validations to work every time with modal dialog boxes will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3516838/1576269) helpful, which is provided by the creator of the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".formLink").click(function() {
        jQuery("#formContainer").modal({
            containerId: "form-container",
            dataId: "form-data",
            onShow: function() {
                attachFormValidations();
            },
            opacity: 60,
            overlayClose: true,
            overlayId: "form-overlay",
        });
    });
    //attachFormValidations(); Remove this line
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had tried that earlier but it did not work somehow.  Feel so dumb now.  :)

Comment: This does not seem to be working under all conditions.  I have modified the sample to include two forms and the validations have stopped working again.  The new sample is at http://jsfiddle.net/NVvFh/35/.  Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NVvFh/36/ Your fields missing `name` attributes required for validation plugin to work.

Comment: Hi Aliaksandr, would appreciate if you could help me resolve this issue I am facing with my production application.  I have uploaded my actual production code at https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0B9FGQtlBq9yeZmMwYmViZTgtZDQ2ZS00NjhiLTk3YjktZWNjMDFiMDA3NmE4&hl=en_GB as a ZIP file.  This file uses exactly the same plugin versions as those on the sample we have been discussing.  However, if you click "Password: Change", close the modal dialog, open the modal again and submit the form, the validations are not triggered. I have spent 3 days without luck on this.